# How to use scanf() without including stdio.h

Tags: c

Is there any possible methods to write a C program without including `stdio.h` as a header file. It was suggested that it can be implemented by declaring `extern int scanf(char* format, ...);`

```
#include <stdio.h> //I want this same code to work without including this line

int main ()
{
  char str [80];
  scanf ("%s",str);  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you think including `stdio.h` is bad?

Comment: You will find that in C, not C++, you need `stdio.h` more often that you think.  For example, in C, where is `NULL` defined?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I just want to know if there are possible solutions.

Comment: @cdarke in <cstdlib> or <cstddef> actually

Comment: Header files aren't magic. `#include` essentially copies the contents of a header file in another one.  You could retype the contents of a header file if you really wanted to.

Comment: I really don't understand why you think `<stdio.h>` has anything at all to do with that other question, or why removing it would somehow help answering that other question. Variadic functions are variadic functions, there's nothing magic about scanf or stdio.h

Comment: @TomTanner: <cstdlib> and <cstddef> are C++.  The C99 standard says NULL is defined in <stddef.h>.

Comment: @cdarke - yes, sorry, mind melting

Comment: @TomTanner:  your point is still valid, NULL is not in stdio by the standard, but I have seen at least one system where it is defined there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can declare the  `scanf` function with:

```
extern int scanf(const char *format, ...);
```

The extern keyword is optional but I like to include it as a reminder of the fact that the function is defined elsewhere.

Your example would then look like:

```
extern int scanf(const char *format, ...);

int main ()
{
  char str [80];
  scanf ("%s",str);  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works only if `scanf` is implemented as a function. There's nothing in the C requirements saying it can't be a macro that invokes some other function such as `fscanf`.

Comment: If it can be used, can you write the code for me. Please edit your answer

Comment: @DavidHammen No.  From section 7.1.4/1, footnote 155 of the ISO C99 standard: "This means that an implementation shall provide an actual function for each library function, even if it also provides a macro for that function." Macros may be provided *in addition* to standard library functions, but they cannot replace them entirely.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Library functions must be implemented as functions. They may also be implemented as macros, but the C standard requires that they be accessible as functions in at least two ways. Per C 2011 (N1570) 7.1.4 1, “Any macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing the name of the function in parentheses, because the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates expansion of a macro function name” and “The use of #undef to remove any macro definition will also ensure that an actual function is referred to.”

Comment: Additionally, the C standard explicitly states that you may declare library functions yourself. C 2011 (N1570) 7.1.4. 2: “Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its associated header.”

Comment: @Niko, just remove the `#include` line and add this one.

Comment: Thanks for this knowledge, please edit your answer and include your above comment.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Why should the `extern` be needed`. The function prototype should be enough imo.

Comment: The `extern` keyword is not needed but I like to include it as a reminder of the fact that the function is defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In C-89, that code would compile without the #include, as function prototypes are optional.

Having said which, it comes under the list of 'really bad things to do' - `scanf` may be a macro, it might have one or more required parameters, ...

So you can do it, but it's like driving at night without any lights. You're liable to crash, even if you think you know the road.